# Apply function to all rows in the loop and put the results in new column

Tags: r

I think that the title explains mostly what I am trying to do. As I am not so experienced with the loop I will need your help.

The data which I have:

```
> dput(data)
structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 778936.666666667, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 2478666.66666667, 2255834.16666667, 0, 1797065.41666667, 
0, 0, 8091450, 10536461.5079365, 0, 2325600, 0, 0, 0, 1011700, 
2049325, 870025, 0, 0, 0, 892385, 3216538.33333333, 960480, 1024325, 
0, 0, 557780, 5798938.88888889, 846266.666666667, 1183267.5, 
0, 0, 1126786.66666667, 7603630.47619048, 888885, 1771708.33333333, 
0, 0, 1557738.33333333, 5441300, 0, 2007712.33333333, 0, 0, 1792833.33333333, 
3435203.33333333, 1913650, 3339118.93939394, 0, 0, 1047475, 2194228.33333333, 
1248360, 973797.916666667, 671265, 0, 804250, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1788100, 1746900, 2140050, 2584000, 0, 947850, 0, 462237.5, 
639437.666666667, 636732.333333333, 0, 0, 0, 508568.333333333, 
1397257.5, 1016524.58333333, 0, 0, 0, 270466.666666667, 742731.785714286, 
408040.681818182, 0, 0, 0, 316706.666666667, 714654.722222222, 
592564.294871795, 0, 0, 0, 255310, 434271.5, 590129.537037037, 
0, 0, 0, 617560, 227435, 367492.5, 0, 0), .Dim = c(6L, 20L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("Greg", "Tommy", "Seb", "Martin", "Alesa", "Yuri"), c("January", 
    "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", 
    "September", "October", "January2", "February2", "March2", 
    "April2", "May2", "June2", "July2", "August2", "September2", 
    "October2")))
```

The vector which is needed for the function:

```
> dput(vec_list)
c(10L, 34L, 59L, 84L, 110L, 134L, 165L, 199L, 234L, 257L, 362L, 
433L, 506L, 581L, 652L, 733L, 818L, 896L, 972L, 1039L)
```

Now the function which I would like to apply to whole data (is much bigger than the given example):

```
work_func <- function(i) data[1,] <- AIC(lm(vec_list~poly(data[1,],i, raw=TRUE)))
as.integer(optimize(work_func,interval = c(1,length(data[1,])-1))$minimum)
```

That's just for a single row. The results of each row should be just a simple number which I would like to put to the new column or just store it as a vector...

Comment: you get the answer in the title: try `apply(data, 1, function(u) ...your function there returning a scalar....)`

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail what your goal is? Do you want to find the minimal AIC for each data row? How is that useful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Colonel correctly noted, you can use `apply` with a margin of 1 here

```
My_func <- function(x) {
                work_func <- function(i) AIC(lm(vec_list ~ poly(x, i, raw = TRUE)))
                as.integer(optimize(work_func, interval = c(1, length(x) - 1))$minimum)
}

apply(data, 1, My_func)
# Greg  Tommy    Seb Martin  Alesa   Yuri 
#    2     12     12      6     18     18
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that `work_func` only really makes sense for integer values of `i`, and is discontinuous, so `optimize` probably isn't the right strategy, instead I've gone with searching all integer values. Using your data,

```
optim_fun <- function(x){
  work_fun <- function(i) AIC(lm(vec_list~poly(x,i, raw=TRUE)))
  which.min(sapply(1:(length(x)-1),work_fun))
}

AIC <- apply(data,1,optim_fun)
```

produces the output

```
> AIC
# Greg  Tommy    Seb Martin  Alesa   Yuri 
# 1     12     15      6      1      2
```

which is the order of polynomial that minimises the AIC for each row.

To explain this a bit, I've just changed work_fun to return the AIC for a power `i` using data `x` set in `optim_fun`. `optim_fun` evaluates `work_fun` at integer values of `i` and finds the `i` that minimises this. The final line applies this to each row of the data in turn.

## Edit

posted almost simultaneously with David Arenburg, so I'll comment quickly on why we get different results - it's down to using `optimize`. My answer finds the slightly lower value for Greg:

```
> work_fun(1)
[1] 294.0098
> work_fun(2)
[1] 294.1508
```

Note that for Seb:

```
> work_fun(12)
[1] 268.0117
> work_fun(13)
[1] 268.0117
> work_fun(14)
[1] 268.0117
> work_fun(15)
[1] 268.0117
```

Likewise, I think my answer is better for Yuri, but all `i` give equal AIC for Alesa, so the answer is undefined.